# FCM push notification in laravel

Tags: firebase, push-notification, laravel-8

I'm trying to send push notification in laravel 8 using Curl in following way :

```
   $headers = array();
   $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
   $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrayToSend);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
   //Send the request
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   //Close request
   if ($response === FALSE) {
       die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);

   return $response;
```

everything is working fine I'm getting the notification.

Issue here is I want to send it in bulk to around 1 Million users, In laravel 8 can we send it in bulk?

Thank you
R

Comment: Its a better practice create a Queue to handle those notifications. Although your app won't respond until the notifications sent.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jobs to send bulk notifications running in background (follow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#creating-jobs)). While your code execute, where you want to send all notifications, just put your job code there and in job handle method add your fcm code.